# Robots Nofollow: I can't find what is the culprit plugin

Tags: php, html, wordpress, indexing, robots.txt

I have a weird problem in astra theme, and Im not savy in php:

I found out my page can't be index by google because of this line
`<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">`

Well, I went to chagpt, google, here and I couldnt find an answer.

Here is the list what I did so far

- I check/uncheck the appearance ->reading : nothing changed
- I deactivate and reactivate YOAST seo: Was not the problem
- Uninstall several plugins for xml sitemaps: no change
- Cleaned several times the cache and the head and footer cache: no success
- Added a `<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">` on the header: Ended to have now 2, one with `content="index"` and other with `content="noindex"` and I presume will have some conflict

The part on the index looks like the culprit is  `<?php wp_head(); ?>`, somehow this injected the nofollow line. Its not between any comment plugin, and I can't find where or which kind of plugin is doing this mess.
Anyone can help me? Thanks

Comment: okay, I found the problem and I will leave the solution here 
Surprised enough was the woo-commerce was blocking the crawlers
Go to ```woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php``` 
Search for index
you will find this function ```function wc_page_noindex() {```
change to allow_index 

I hope this help someone